# How to make an Anchor tag to redirect to a particular section of another html page?

Tags: html, css

I want to know what i should put in the href="" section of the  tag so that, when i click on it, it should take me to a particular section of another html page.

i only know that if i put the id of a section as href, then it should take me to a section of the same page. But what about other page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go to a specific section **in the same page**, create a hyperlink by using the id of the link target, preceded by #:

```html
<a href="#section">Jump to the part of the page with the “section” id</a>
```

If you want to go a specific section **in another page**, the same way but after the page link:

Link to another page in the same domain:

```html
<a href="/another-page.html#section">Go to the HTML Links in our website.</a>
```

Link to another page in different domain:

```html
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page#wikipedia">Go to the main page of Wikipedia</a>
```